# error while trying to push branches to remote repository

Tags: git

I recently did some interactive rebase and now I am not able to push the branches I rebased.

```
To https://github.com/user/remoteRepo.git
 ! [rejected]        Refactor1 -> Refactor1 (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
```

how do i resolve this and take care to avoid this?

Comment: Can you pull into the branches first, then try pushing them? I don't know if that will work in your specific situation, but it usually helps me when I have trouble pushing.

Comment: if i pull those branches the i think what I `squash` to single commit might be of no use..

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase` rewrites history.
`git push` won't let you push any commits with a different history than the remote already has.

To forcefully blow away the current remote history, use `git push -f`.

This will break any other existing clones that try to pull the new history.